# Setear valor por defecto de un form con django

Tags: python, django, django-forms

Estoy haciendo UN CRUD de Usuario, y quiero agregar un valor de estado = activo por defecto a todo usuario que se cree, hasta el momento no he dado con la forma correcta de agregar este valor y sea generado correctamente el usuario, agradecería saber como poder hacerlo

En el view me gustaría setear el valor por defecto estado = activo, actualmente lo tengo de la siguiente manera, la consola me informa http/1.1 500 pero no se enviá el formulario

```
def crearUsuario(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        UsuarioForm.field['estado'].initial = 'activo' #acá mi ultimo intento
        formaUsuario = UsuarioForm(request.POST)
        if formaUsuario.is_valid():
            formaUsuario.save()
            return redirect('usuarios')
    else:
        formaUsuario = UsuarioForm()
    return render(request, 'usuarios/crearUsuario.html', {'formaUsuario':formaUsuario})
```

El estado lo estoy ocultando del formulario para que no se llene de la siguiente manera

```
{% for field in formaUsuario %}
{% if field.name != 'estado' %}
<div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-4 col-xs-6" style="margin-bottom: 5px">
    {{ field.errors }}
    {{ field.label_tag }}
    {{ field }}
    <p></p>
</div>
{% endfor %}
```

Finalmente este es el formulario que cree

```
class UsuarioForm(forms.Form):
    rut = forms.CharField(label='Rut', widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder':'Ejemplo: 12345678-8'}))
    nombre = forms.CharField(label='Nombre')
    apePat = forms.CharField(label='Apellido Paterno')
    apeMat = forms.CharField(label='Apellido Materno')
    correo = forms.CharField(label='Correo electronico', widget=forms.EmailInput(attrs={'placeholder':'tuCorreo@mail.cl'}))
    estado = forms.CharField()
```

Answer (score 1):

Vas por buen camino amigo, el error que te da probablemente es por que no sabe donde guardar tu informacion ya que estas usando forms.Form entonces tienes que indicar la logica de guardado en tu vista dentro del if formaUsuario.is_valid().

Entonces lo que te recomendaria seria utilizar un modelform el cual ya se encarga de realizar la parte del guardado, cambia tu form de esta manera:

```
class UsuarioForm(forms.ModelForm):
    rut = forms.CharField(label='Rut', widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder':'Ejemplo: 12345678-8'}))
    nombre = forms.CharField(label='Nombre')
    # Tus demas campos
    # .....

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(FormPerfilEgresoOfertaEducativa, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        # Definir campo como oculto
        self.fields['estado'].widget = forms.HiddenInput()

        # No existe instancia ni su pk, entonces est
        if not self.instance.pk:
            self.fields['estado'].initial = 'activo'


    class Meta:
        model = TuModelo # Aqui pon el nombre de tu modelo e importalo
        fields = '__all__'
```

Tu view quedaría de la siguiente manera:

```
def crearUsuario(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        formaUsuario = UsuarioForm(request.POST)
        if formaUsuario.is_valid():
            formulario = form.save(commit=False)
            # si no estableces el estado activo en el form de arriba tambien puedes ponerlo aqui o modificar otro campo que tu quieras
            # formulario.estado = 'activo'
            formulario.save()

            return redirect('usuarios')
    else:
        formaUsuario = UsuarioForm()
    return render(request, 'usuarios/crearUsuario.html', {'formaUsuario':formaUsuario})
```

Y por ultimo tu template pensado usando clases de bootstrap 4:

```
{% block content %}
    <h2>Nuevo</h2>
    <form method="POST" class="post-form">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <!-- Renderear campos ocultos -->
        {% for hidden in formaUsuario.hidden_fields %}
            {{ hidden }}
        {% endfor %}
        <!-- Renderear errores no relacionados a los campos -->
        {% if formaUsuario.non_field_errors %}
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-12 alert alert-danger">
                    {{ formaUsuario.non_field_errors }}
                </div>
            </div>
        {% endif %}
        <div class="row">
            <!-- Renderear todos tus campos visibles -->
            {% for field in form.visible_fields %}

                <!-- Aqui puedes personalizar el diseño de tus campos -->
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="{% if field.errors %}inputError{% else %}{{ field.id_for_label }}{% endif %}"
                        class="control-label">
                        {{ field.label }}{% if field.field.required %}<span class="text-danger">*</span>{% endif %}</label>
                        {{ field }}
                        {% if field.errors %}
                            <span class="invalid-feedback">{{ field.errors.as_text }}</span>
                        {% endif %}
                    </div>
                </div>
            {% endfor %}
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="save btn btn-default">Guardar</button>
    </form>
{% endblock %}
```

Espero esto te sirva de guía para poder lograr tu objetivo.